# while true with delay

Tags: java, while-loop

I normally use infinite loop as in the way below:

```
public static boolean start = false;

while(!start) {
    doMyLogic();
}
```

but a friend said you need to have a small delay inside the while-true loop (like bellow), otherwise it may tend to cause memory issues and also it is not a good practice.

Suggested way:

```
while(!start) { 
    Thread.sleep(few_miliseconds);  // 500 ms
    doMyLogic();
}
```

Kindly advise me the impact of suggested way. Am I doing it right?

Comment: 500 ms isn't exactly a small delay :)

Comment: This looks all right, it depends on what the doMyLogic() method is doing which will determine how long to sleep for and if it is an infinite loop why not just have a while(true)?

Comment: It may not be an infinite loop since the start variable is a public variable.  It's possible (though generally not good practice) that doMyLogic method changes the start variable.

Comment: while(true) usually generates a compiler warning.

Comment: you could also use `for (;;) {}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I don't think it would have memory issues (unless your doMyLogic method has memory issues), because any memory leaks will manifest themselves regardless of the delay.  The real benefit of the sleep is that in most instances, the code doesn't need to be doMyLogic as fast as the computer can.  For example, let's say doMyLogic is checking to see if a file was created in a directory.  It would not be necessary to have the computer check several hundred times a second for that scenario (which would require a lot of CPU and disk I/O), when 1 time a second may be sufficient.

The biggest impact of not having the timing is using extra CPU time and other resources that your logic function has, in most cases with no discernable impact to the end user.

Answer (score 3):

I would use a ScheduledExecutorService

```
ScheduledExecutorService service = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
service.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        doMyLogic();
    }
}, 500, 500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

This service can be re-used for many repeating or delayed tasks and can be `shutdown()` as required.

Answer (score 2):

Not memory issues, but you are blocking CPU. Definitely use a delay.

It also depends a bit on the `doMyLogic()` method.

Comment: If you're worried about blocking, then you want to yield, not sleep.

Answer (score 2):

It's always a good practice to insert sleep in a (semi) infinite loop so when code execution reaches the sleep, other threads can be executed too.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have a pause, your CPU is constantly doing something. You are effectively blocking the CPU. However, if you add a pause (sleep()) you give the CPU a break to do other things.